# How to Convert integer to decimal in oracle

Tags: oracle, integer, decimal

how can i convert a integer to decimal in oracle? Is there any function like TO_CHAR? 
I need to put this function on a where clause. Thanks

```
SELECT IDDS,
       ID
FROM   T_TABLEONE
WHERE  CAST(ID as DECIMAL)='1,301131832E19';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you apply a function to the column then you can run the risks of:

1. being unable to use a regular index on that column
2. obscuring the expected cardinality of the result set, which can cause query optimisation problems.

So it's generally a bad practice, and you'd do better to cast your literal to the same type as the column, in this case using to_number().

However in this case I'm surprised that it's necessary, as Oracle's type conversion in recent releases should be able to cope with comparing an integer column to a number expressed in scientific notation: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/336d3/8

Answer (score 0):

Use [CAST](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions016.htm):

```
CAST(myInt AS DECIMAL)
```

Comment: Where Convert(ID,decimal);  What are you comparing against?

Comment: I show you the code:
    
`code:
    SELECT IDDS,
    ID
    FROM T_TABLEONE WHERE CAST(ID as DECIMAL)='1,301131832E19';
`
    
But nothing.. I don't know if is correct.. Inside the ID field there are the numbers that i have to convert (for example this one 1,301131832E19). Doesn't work :( how can i write it?